# stretch image over div

Tags: html, css, image, stretch

I have a gallery and the thumbnails are set to have a width of 100%. however some images do not fill the full height of this div.

How do I get it so that the images stretch over the full width and height of the div? (can't be changed to background images)

```
<div class="gallery-grid">
    <div class="section group">
        <div class="col span_1_of_6">
        <a href="javascript: changeImage(1);"><img src="images/flowers.jpg"  alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_6">
        <a href="javascript: changeImage(2);"><img src="images/back.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_6">
        <a href="javascript: changeImage(3);"><img src="images/flowers.jpg"  alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_6">
        <a href="javascript: changeImage(4);"><img src="images/back.jpg"  alt="" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col span_1_of_6">
        <a href="javascript: changeImage(5);"><img src="images/flowers.jpg"  alt="" /></a>
        </div>
            <div class="col span_1_of_6">
        <a href="javascript: changeImage(6);"><img src="images/back.jpg"  alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>



 <!--style-->
    .gallery-grid img{
        width:100%;
    }
```

Comment: Do the thumbnails all have the same height/width ratio?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. You must have some other css affecting it. See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGmRBW

```
.gallery-grid img{
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gallery-grid .section .col a{
    display: block;
}
.gallery-grid .section .col a img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You should consider that `a` is an inline element, so to put an image propely in it, you may need to set its `display` property correctly.

## In action

```css
a{
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>The parent anchor has 100x100 dimensions:</p>
<p>The child image has 100x50 dimensions:</p>

<a href=""><img src="https://placehold.it/100x50"></a>
```